Not able to access VM from host
I have kali linux in Virtual box and windows 10 as my main OS but when I try to access Kali linux from any external host through IP address of Kali linux then Kali linux cannot respond and when I used to ping it from command prompt then do not response with any packet even Firewall status is inactive in kali linux but it is not responding. Whats solution?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

change to "bridged adapter'' in vbox network settings!!

I change it to bridged adapter but still not works

Most clearly I have Kali linux in Virtualbox as a VM I want to access VM from my host Windows 10 through IP of kali linux by using chrome when I search as IP of Kali linux in Chrome then it gives the error that Beneficiary is not responding means Kali linux is not responding. This is problem whats solution that I have accessed it
